# How correct using BIO_f_zlib() function in openssl C

Tags: c, encoding, openssl

I'm search how using zlib in openssl and not found. I need minimal example similar BIO tsdin/out or base64

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: You myst add zlib header